# Method and parameter naming conforming to Swift API Design Guideline

Tags: api, swift3

It's not obvious to me from reading the current API design guideline, which of the following version is better.

```
class MediaLoader {}
class MediaRequest {}

let mediaLoader = MediaLoader()
let mediaRequest = MediaRequest()

// Option 1
mediaLoader.add(request: mediaRequest)

// Option 2
mediaLoader.add(mediaRequest: mediaRequest)

// Option 3
mediaLoader.addRequest(mediaRequest)

// Option 4
mediaLoader.add(mediaRequest)
```

Which of the above conforms to the current API design guideline the best?

Comment: WWDC 2016 [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/403/) walks you through some practical examples of deciding what an API should look like.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on the purpose and semantics of MediaLoader.  If MediaLoader is only a collection of mediaRequests, then .add(mediaRequest) is the way to go because it would flow grammatically and be meaningful in context.

On the other hand, if a mediaRequest is merely one of many different things contributing to its purpose, then .add() alone would not convey enough context to properly read the statement.   For example, if you could also add display channels or filters, then merely saying .add(something) would not be clear enough.  This is when you would use an extended name that describes the relationship.  e.g.   .addRequest(),  addChannel(), addFilter().

But not .add(request:...), because, using a name for the first parameter is not the ideal way to distinguish between relationships.  It should be used instead to clarify the method by which the addition will be performed or the way the request will be accessed. This will leave the "nameless" variant for the most frequent and straightforward use case.  e.g. .add(fromTemplate:webRequesTemplate) or .addRequest(fromTemplate:webTemplate).